# How to calculate an integral with a Heaviside function: $\int_{0}^{t} {sinh(2(t - \tau))*u_{T}(\tau)d\tau}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to calculate this integral, resulting from convolution method: $\int_{0}^{t} {\sinh(2(t - \tau))*u_{T}(\tau)d\tau}$, where $u_{T}(\tau)$ is a Heaviside function.

I have tried integrating it by parts, but it does not work. I was not bale to apply substitution method either.

EDIT: Using equality $\sinh{t} = \frac{e^{t} - e^{-t}}{2}$ gives:
$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}{e^{2(t - \tau)}u_{T}(\tau)d\tau} - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}{e^{-2(t - \tau)}u_{T}(\tau)d\tau}$. But the biggest problem is that I do not understand how to integrate Heaviside function, so I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Try an addition theorem for $\sinh$. Or, simpler, use the substitution $u = t - \tau$.

Comment: What does the $T$ in $u_T$ stand for? And apparently you are considering some kind of half-convolution where the functions are only non-zero on the positive half axis.

Comment: $u_{T}(t)$ is equal to one if $t \ge T$ and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand is non-trivial for $0\le τ\le t$ and $T\leτ$. The interval collapses for $t<T$. These cases are all captured with an integration interval $[\max(0,T),\max(t,T)]$.
$$
((\sinh2)*u_T)(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\sinh(2(t-τ))·u(τ-T)dτ
=\int_{\max(0,T)}^{\max(t,T)}\sinh(2(t-τ))dτ\\
=-\frac12(\cosh(2t-2\max(t,T))-\cosh(2t-2\max(0,T)))\\
=-\frac12(\cosh(2\min(0,t-T))-\cosh(2\min(t,t-T)))\\
$$

$$
=\begin{cases}
\frac12(\cosh(2t)-1)&T≤0\\
\frac12(\cosh(2(t-T))-1)&0≤ T≤t\\
0&t≤T
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1. $t < T$: In this case $0 < \tau < t < T$ so the Heaviside function is always one and

   $$
    \int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\; \sinh(2(t-\tau))u_T(\tau) = \int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\; \sinh(2(t-\tau)) = \sinh^2 t
    $$
2. $t > T$: The Heaviside function will vanish for $0 <\tau < T$, therefore

   $$
    \int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\; \sinh(2(t-\tau))u_T(\tau) = \int_T^t {\rm d}\tau\; \sinh(2(t-\tau)) = \sinh^2 (t-T)
    $$